# Python mock and call assertion

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I am trying to write a python unit test to assert that a scoped_session .commit() is called.

main.py

```
from database import DBSession

def deactivate_user(user_id):
    db_session = DBSession()
    user = User(db_session).get(user_id)
    user.is_active = False
    db_session.commit()

def get_account(user_id):
    pass
```

database.py

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
import settings

session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=create_engine(settings.CONNECTION_STRING))
DBSession = scoped_session(session_factory)
```

unit_test.py

```
from main import deactivate_user

def test_deactivate_user(mocker)
    mocked_account = mocker.patch('main.get_account', return_value=get_test_account())
    mocked_session = mocker.patch('database.DBSession', autospec=True)
    deactivate_user(123)
    mocked_account.assert_called()
    mocked_session.commit.assert_called()
```

`mocked_account.assert_called()` works correctly.

However, `mocked_session.commit.assert_called()` does not work.

`E   AssertionError: Expected 'commit' to have been called.`

Other relevant information:

`type(mocked_session) == <class 'unittest.mock.MagicMock'>`

`mocked_session.mock_calls == []`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was patching in the wrong place. When I changed

`mocked_session = mocker.patch('database.DBSession', autospec=True)`

to

`mocked_session = mocker.patch('main.DBSession', autospec=True)`

it worked

Comment: Yes and is exactly what I have written in my answer with the use of unittest module.

Comment: Sorry the relevant information got completely lost in your answer with the suggestion to layout the test completely different which is a non runner for me.

Comment: OK I understand, you don't use my test environment and I don't use yours. Your ither test `mocked_account.assert_called()` is a bit strange. I don't understand it, but may be It's only a my problem.

Answer (score 0):

About the test of the calling of the method `commit()` I suggest you to write this new test code (it use the `unittest` moodule):

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from main import deactivate_user

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_deactivate_user(test):
            with mock.patch('main.DBSession', autospec=True) as mocked_session:
                mocked_session_instance = mocked_session.return_value
                deactivate_user(123)
                mocked_session_instance.commit.assert_called()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

In your code by the following instruction:

```
mocked_session = mocker.patch('database.DBSession', autospec=True)
```

you have substituted (by a Mock object) the object pointed by the name `DBSession` in the module `database`.
But you have to substitute the object pointed by the name `DBSession` in the module `main`, and this is possible with:

```
with mock.patch('main.DBSession', autospec=True) as mocked_session:
    mocked_session_instance = mocked_session.return_value
```